# Default permissions for "Program Files" folder?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, default-settings

I modified the default permissions of "Program files" and now some things aren't working (Windows Mail isn't opening)

What are the default permissions of "Program files" so that I can reset it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it through a VM.

The two main ones I needed to add to get my apps to work again were:

- NT Service\TrustedInstaller
- ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES

Otherwise here's the entire default permission set:

[image]

Some of them need to be specified with their full object name, e.g. "TrustedInstaller" is actually "NT Service\TrustedInstaller", and there's "ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES" which I couldn't find the full object name of.