# Main account not listed under permissions in Windows 10, only "users" after fresh install, is this normal?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

Fresh install yesterday, but already having tons of permission issues doing stuff as simple as deleting folders, on secondary drives no less.

The main thing I wanted to ask about was comparing to examples of permissions I've seen online my user account isn't specifically listed as having any access to anything, instead there's only a generic **"users"** account in it's place.

I'm the only account on the machine, so I'm not sure if this is normal for accounts signed in to MS, or for single user systems, or if due to my settings being synced to an account, that maybe some bad permissions have carried over to the new install as a default?

[image]

This is the case across the whole machine. So before I do anything dumb I wanted to get a second opinion.

Comment: Why are you wondering that you don't have permissions to Windows-owned folders like `C:\Program Files`? That's a very bad example to give.

Comment: This dialog is worthless.  Open "computer management".. open "Local users and groups".. look for your user.  Double click user and go to "Member of" tab.  Screen shot that if you haven't figured out what's going on yet... actually.. edit.. @John is right.. I didn't even see that.  You are already a member of administrators.  You need to learn about file permissions I am betting.. no offense.

Comment: If that's the case why am I getting errors like "you need permission from (name of my user account) to edit this folder" when trying to delete stuff on my secondary drives?

Comment: Why so pissed about the dialogue? I'm only following the example of a highly reputable member's answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1299363/default-permissions-for-program-files-folder 
I do understand permissions, but Windows is fickle and a bad setting can cause serious issues. Having issues possibly related to permissions on a fresh install, it just made sense to rule it out 100% as the cause as my system appeared different to examples I'd seen. Why's that such a crime? I can't learn if I don't ask. but maybe you could learn some manners? No offense. I'll even say please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly did a fresh install (all new Windows), your first user (Gibsonfx) is a member of the Administrators group and that is what your image above suggests. The other users (System, Trusted Installer) are normal system users.  So it appears normal.  You can look at Users and Groups to verify

Comment: Thanks, but why do other screen caps I've seen of this exact window show other people as being listed by their main account name and not "users"?

Comment: Look in Users and Groups (Computer Management) to see the users in a normal form. Right click on My Computer (This PC) and select Computer Managment

Comment: I have already checked that yes it's the account listed under there, but I'm getting a lot of permission errors when trying to edit folders in my one drive etc so I'm just trying to rule out the cause.

Comment: Did you use precisely the same main user account?

Comment: For One Drive? Yeah when I install windows I enter my email and PW, then it sets up the account, it doesn't give me any opportunity to change anything, i.e. user name ect. if that's what you mean?

Comment: If the email and password is the same then sign out of One Drive and sign back in again.

Comment: LOL yeah I've tried that half a dozen times over the last 24 or so hours. Sometimes it seemed like it helped for a moment, but then it stops working again. I'm usually pretty good at trouble shooting issues, I've been trying every guide I can find, so we can skip past the obvious stuff. It's also happening outside of One Drive as well on different drives entirely, One Drive is just were I've experienced it the most since that's where I've been making the most changes.

Comment: One frequent times it occurs is related to long file path names over 255 characters which Windows/OneDrive doesn't like, but I work in web development using One Drive to backup site files, which always have ridiculous numbers of nested files like 20-30+ folders deep and special characters, but that's not something I have much control over, it's the nature of Website file systems. But again, while that seems to be a factor some cases, it doesn't explain a lot of others, especially when the majority of such folders with long file paths remain unaffected and have done for years before now.